# Building Time and Energy Consumption App

Tags: android, performance, battery

My start to build android which is checking battery consumption and performance for android phone.

For the first step, i would like to build the app(or method) which can consume a lot of battery( and some amount of execution time like 10 sec to 1 mins)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230783/memory-usage-and-energy-consumption

I  researched possible function that I can use for studying android app.

From research , rotating image can consume a lot of battery and some amount of time.

However, I would like to find more functions (or methods) which possibly use a lot of battery and time.

Does any one can suggest good method ?

Answer (score 0):

The most energy consuming apps are those that keep the processor from falling into an idle state. An idle state is when the processor isn't doing anything so the hardware/software power management shuts down parts of the processor and peripherals. Computationally intensive routines, such as some types of rotations, will keep the processor busy, preventing it from dropping into a lower power idle state. This is why someone recommended some image processing.

Even so, such libraries often check for certain common situations where a more efficient/less computationally intensive algorithm can be used. Additionally, a visual processing app may do things that can cause periods of idle.

I recommend using a simple floating point or double precision matrix multiply with all compiler optimizations disabled. Use non-trivial matrices. Throw an external loop around it to increase the length of the run. Multi-thread it so that if you have multiple cores, something will be running on those cores.

The advantage of this approach is that you have control over the type, length and intensity of the processing.

--
Taylor